# No consigo el token de facebook

Tags: android, facebook, autenticación

Hola estoy realizando la autenticación de Facebook mediante el callback de la clase AccessTokenTracker , onCurrentAccessTokenChanged , el problema es que nunca se me ejecuta y no puedo tener acceso al AccessToken para ver los datos. He seguido la documentación y aún así despúes de ejecutarse el método 
FacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
no se ejecuta nada más. El código que tendo está dentro de un Fragment y es el siguiente:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getContext());
CallbackManager mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
AccessTokenTracker mFacebookAccessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
    @Override
    protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken  currentAccessToken) {
           // AQUI NO SE EJECUTA NUNCA
      }  
}   };
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null)
    // NO ENTRA NUNCA
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
    View view;
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_layout, container, false);
    btnFacebook = (LoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.sign_conectar_f) ;
    btnFacebook.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");
    btnFacebook.setFragment(this);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);                               
        mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falto agregar el registerCallback a tu boton, ese te va a retornar un loginResult, con el loginResult obtenes el accesstoken.

```
btnFacebook.registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    ...
    String token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
    ...
}

@Override
public void onCancel() {
    //usuario no dio permiso
}

@Override
public void onError(FacebookException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

});